# Why Windows 10 does not see Nodemcu device?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, windows, ch340

- I am using a Windows 10 laptop. Behind the nodemcu it says that download CH340G driver.
- I already had arduino ide and the esp libraries were already
  installed because i was using a esp8266 01 device before.
- I bought a Nodemcu i downloaded the driver for it CH340G driver.
- When i install the driver it says that The drive is successfully
  pre-installed in advance!
- When I plug my Nodemcu to my computer with a new cable blue lights
  come from the board and it stops. And windows doesn't make a sound
  which indicates that it sees the device.
- I don't think the nodemcu is the problem. How do i fix this?

Comment: so are you are not able to see the nodemcu in arduino

Comment: In arduino IDE i can see the nodemcu in the cards section but when it is plugged in there are no ports attached to the nodemcu. Windows does not see it

Comment: so what's the problem if u can see it in Arduino then you can upload code to the node muc please tell me what you want .

Comment: If Windows doesn't make a sound then it doesn't see the device being plugged in. Are you sure you're usb cable has data wires in it?

Comment: does your board have a CH340G chip?

Comment: you could also try deleting the driver you installed . it may be conflicting with win10 . also windows installs necessary driver for any new device .

Comment: I tried this on 3 computers 2 of them are windows 10 and one mac and they did not work either. I bought a new usb-mini cable which says that it has 48bps transfer rate. I think it is a decent cable for nodemcu. I also tried this without installing drivers and also it did not work. But when i plug the card to the computer the cards lights flashes then they stop. So i think it means that the card works right?

Comment: Also when i plug the nodemcu to my computer windows does not make a sound of recognition for the device.

Comment: it could be a problem with the usb port on ur node mcu  it may be oxidized . because windows doesn't make any sound until a device data pins are connected .

Comment: I tried it with multiple devices so usb port should not be an issue. Also cable is okay. :(

Comment: I have had nodemcu clones from China where the soldering of the USB socket is bad. You may need to resolder the socket.

Comment: This is probably it... I can not find another way for this not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007501/nodemcu-not-detected-by-computer#:~:text=I%20had%20to%20install%20the,Afterwards%2C%20it%20worked.&text=For%20future%20people%20with%20this,and%20it%20wouldn't%20detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007501/nodemcu-not-detected-by-computer#:%7E:text=I%20had%20to%20install%20the,Afterwards%2C%20it%20worked.&text=For%20future%20people%20with%20this,and%20it%20wouldn%27t%20detect). and  also search few ways to remove oxidation from pins like using autosol (I have never used it ) . Try uploading code through FTDI modules or just get it replaced.